# Can't connect to any repository

Tags: egit, eclipse-neon

I am using egit with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500. I am using the default connection settings. I have pushed multiple times but today my team and I faced the below error while pushing.

```
Can't connect to any repository: 
https://github.com/Project/proj1.git 
(https://github.com/Project/proj1.git: Connection reset)
```

I have changed the project name in the above. I am able to connect to the remote repository in the browser.

Comment: Did you recently change your connection credentials like password. If you have password saved, you have to update it.

Comment: Yes that was it. Can you add your answer as a post so I can accept. Can you up vote this question. Thanks.

Comment: Took you one year to verify my comment. That's funny. Just kidding.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Sometimes you get carried away with other tasks. Appreciate your help.